# MongoDB in a Docker Container

Tags: mongodb, docker

I am trying to run mongodb in a container. I am also trying move the data file into a volume, so that I can keep my data even after I stop the container. The problem happens when I try to run the image.
I need to point mongodb to a new config file when starting it. For this I use

```
ENTRYPOINT mongod --config /mongo_data/configuraton/mongod.conf
```

But the container exits immediately.

On the other hand, if I just write

```
ENTRYPOINT mongod
```

it works fine. Any idea?

This is my dockerfile from which I've build the image

```
FROM mongo

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install nano

VOLUME /mongo_data

ENTRYPOINT mongod --config /mongo_data/configuraton/mongod.conf
```

Comment: Why just not use the official image mongo:X.XX.X?

Comment: Because I would like to keep my data after I stop the container.

Comment: Why you can't create volume for the data directory?

Comment: That's what I am trying to do, But to do that I need to create a new config file and point mongo to it.

Comment: You don't... Take the official image and mount to /data/db into the container...